# Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined, express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mern

Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined, just seemed to randomly appear! I have no idea where it's coming from or why it is there. It's incredibly frustrating! All the browser is telling me is that it's coming from express, but obviously I've not modified the library so the error message is pretty much useless.

```
response.js:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (response.js:42)
at Object../node_modules/express/lib/response.js (response.js:1142)
```

So anyway I have built a MERN message board and integrated chat and webrtc videocalling with socket.io, and suddenly this error starts to appear. Oh, and I think it's important to note that I used  create-react-app for my client, so I'm not dealing with webpack, myself.

I'm so clueless at the moment so please somebody help me out, here.

Comment: Did you check the code in node_modules? `(response.js:1142)`

Comment: what should i look for?

Comment: i just installed response on the server but the error is still showing. I'm clueless atm

Comment: This is the code in line 42 `var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)`, probably something wrong with `http.ServerResponse` I'm clueless too

Comment: Remove `node_modules` and install packages again

Comment: on the server, right?

Comment: Yes where you have express installed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222491/discussion-between-matrixersp-and-harry-young).

Comment: same issue still

Comment: somehow this line was auto imported in react:
import { response } from 'express';
i hate when that happens

Answer (score 1):

somehow this line was auto imported in react: import { response } from 'express'; i hate when that happens